# office365ConnectorSend - not able to get the desired colour in the MS teams message

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, office365connectors

I am trying to use office365ConnectorSend to send message from Jenkins to MS Teams and the colour attribute seems to be not working at all.

I am using something like below in Jenkins pipeline file as per https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Office-365-Connector/

office365ConnectorSend (message: "Test Notification", color: "ffc000", webhookUrl: "webhoook url")

I am able to get the message to my teams channel but Whatever hex code I use, the message card color doesn't change at all.

Comment: I am seeing this as well.

Jenkins - v2.263.4
Office 365 Connector - v4.14.0

Comment: Has anyone been able to solve this?